# Curator ServiceCacheListener is triggered three times when a service is added

Tags: apache-zookeeper, service-discovery, apache-curator

I am learning zookeeper and trying out the Curator framework for service discoveries. However, I am facing a weird issue that I have difficulties to figure out. The problem is when I tried to register an instance via `serviceDiscovery`, the `cacheChanged` event of the `serviceCache` gets triggered three times. When I removed an instance, it is only triggered once, which is the expected behavior. Please see the code below:

```
public class DiscoveryExample {

    private static String PATH = "/base";
    static ServiceDiscovery<InstanceDetails> serviceDiscovery = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CuratorFramework client = null;


        try {
            // this is the ip address of my VM
            client = CuratorFrameworkFactory.newClient("192.168.149.129:2181", new ExponentialBackoffRetry(1000, 3));
            client.start();

            JsonInstanceSerializer<InstanceDetails> serializer = new JsonInstanceSerializer<InstanceDetails>(
                    InstanceDetails.class);
            serviceDiscovery = ServiceDiscoveryBuilder.builder(InstanceDetails.class)
                    .client(client)
                    .basePath(PATH)
                    .serializer(serializer)
                    .build();
            serviceDiscovery.start();

            ServiceCache<InstanceDetails> serviceCache = serviceDiscovery.serviceCacheBuilder()
                    .name("product")
                    .build();

            serviceCache.addListener(new ServiceCacheListener() {

                @Override
                public void stateChanged(CuratorFramework curator, ConnectionState state) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    System.out.println("State Changed to " + state.name());
                }

                // THIS IS THE PART GETS TRIGGERED MULTIPLE TIMES
                @Override
                public void cacheChanged() {
                    System.out.println("Cached Changed ");
                    List<ServiceInstance<InstanceDetails>> list = serviceCache.getInstances();

                    Iterator<ServiceInstance<InstanceDetails>> it = list.iterator();
                    while(it.hasNext()) {
                        System.out.println(it.next().getAddress());
                    }
                }
            });
            serviceCache.start();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.print("> ");
            String line = in.readLine();


        } finally {
            CloseableUtils.closeQuietly(serviceDiscovery);
            CloseableUtils.closeQuietly(client);
        }
    }
}
```

AND

```
public class RegisterApplicationServer {

    final static String PATH = "/base";
    static ServiceDiscovery<InstanceDetails> serviceDiscovery = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CuratorFramework client = null;

        try {
            client = CuratorFrameworkFactory.newClient("192.168.149.129:2181", new ExponentialBackoffRetry(1000, 3));
            client.start();

            JsonInstanceSerializer<InstanceDetails> serializer = new JsonInstanceSerializer<InstanceDetails>(
                    InstanceDetails.class);
            serviceDiscovery = ServiceDiscoveryBuilder.builder(InstanceDetails.class).client(client).basePath(PATH)
                    .serializer(serializer).build();
            serviceDiscovery.start();

            // SOME OTHER CODE THAT TAKES CARES OF USER INPUT...

        } finally {
            CloseableUtils.closeQuietly(serviceDiscovery);
            CloseableUtils.closeQuietly(client);
        }
    }

    private static void addInstance(String[] args, CuratorFramework client, String command,
            ServiceDiscovery<InstanceDetails> serviceDiscovery) throws Exception {
        // simulate a new instance coming up
        // in a real application, this would be a separate process

        if (args.length < 2) {
            System.err.println("syntax error (expected add <name> <description>): " + command);
            return;
        }

        StringBuilder description = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 1; i < args.length; ++i) {
            if (i > 1) {
                description.append(' ');
            }
            description.append(args[i]);
        }

        String serviceName = args[0];
        ApplicationServer server = new ApplicationServer(client, PATH, serviceName, description.toString());
        server.start();

        serviceDiscovery.registerService(server.getThisInstance());
        System.out.println(serviceName + " added");
    }

    private static void deleteInstance(String[] args, String command, ServiceDiscovery<InstanceDetails> serviceDiscovery) throws Exception {
        // in a real application, this would occur due to normal operation, a
        // crash, maintenance, etc.

        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.err.println("syntax error (expected delete <name>): " + command);
            return;
        }

        final String serviceName = args[0];
        Collection<ServiceInstance<InstanceDetails>> set = serviceDiscovery.queryForInstances(serviceName); 
        Iterator<ServiceInstance<InstanceDetails>> it = set.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            ServiceInstance<InstanceDetails> si = it.next();
            if (si.getPayload().getDescription().indexOf(args[1]) != -1) {
                serviceDiscovery.unregisterService(si);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Removed an instance of: " + serviceName);
    }

}
```

I appriciate if anyone can please point out where I am doing wrong and maybe can share some good materials/examples so I can refer to. The official website and the examples on github does not help a lot.